what happens when a erc20 token is transferred?
I believe there are no "physical" tokens in the sense that nothing really is transferred, just the erc20 token contract updates the balances of the sender and recipient.
Is my understanding correct?
I'm confused because that would mean for tokens like USDT on ethereum, it has to maintain the balances of all the users who have it. And it does do that but then what about things like adding liquidity to liquidity pools on DEXes? How does that work in regards to the erc20 token contracts just updating the balances?

You are correct the contract has a mapping of address to balance address=>uint256.
A pool is just another holder, in most cases. If you look at a list of holders for a token, liquidity pools will usually be found near the top of the list.
There are implementations where the tokens will be held in a vault contract or something other than the pool contract, but to the same effect.
The liquidity provider receives LP tokens, or these days can be an NFT, that represents a share of the pool.
When they leave the pool they redeem that share for a portion of the pools tokens.
They don't retain their balance when they deposit to a pool, and so they mapping is updated on a transfer just as it would be between two eoa's (externally owned accounts).

Is there a limit to the number of holders and their balances a token contract can keep track of?

The total storage a contract can access is: 2^256 * 32 bytes, from Vitalik: "There are 2^256 different keys, and each key can store 32 bytes, so that's a total of 2^261 bytes that could be stored. That said, by then the Ethereum blockchain will probably break due to a hash collision...."
